# Are there collections/listings/ratings of "bad" music?

Tags: charts, compilations

A lot of us are probably familiar with the [World's Ugliest Dog Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World's_Ugliest_Dog_Contest); are there similar contests/collections/ratings of "bad" music?

Note that this is not a subjective question asking what *you* think bad music is, but rather an objective question asking if any such collections exist, however the idea of "bad" may be defined.

Comment: It's hard to define *bad*... but an objective rating would be something about the lowest sales regarding invested money?

Comment: Good point; I've edited the question to clarify that any definition of "bad" is acceptable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_considered_the_worst

Comment: @topomorto: The fact that Lou Reed appears on this list *twice* shows it to be rather worthless.

Comment: @JanJohannsen I guess part of being a great artist is that you test the boundaries...

Comment: If I were to make such a list, it would have been really huge. Almost 90% of all music would have been in that list.

Comment: Paradoxically, to figure on such a list a song would have to be famous enough, i.e. to be sold or be played enough to be noticed, i.e. to be liked by a large amount of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I did see the Wiki one and it is posted in the comments. I was able to see a top 100 list that that differs some.

I think while looking, that it really is a preference in what one would like to consider is indeed a list of terrible songs.

The bizarre part is most songs are in the top 10 and many in the top 5 of best selling songs.

Anyhow here is a list.
http://www.notinhalloffame.com/rock-and-roll/100-worst-songs-of-modern-pop-culture